# Passing sql row id to tableview in corona

Tags: sql, lua, tableview, coronasdk

This is my code and working fine so far

```
local count = 0
for row in db:nrows("select unit.id, builtin_list.* from unit inner join builtin_list on unit.id = builtin_list.unit_id group by artist order by artist asc") do
    count = count+1
    song[count]={}
    song[count].artist = row.artist
end

-- all done with db. close it
db:close()

local function tableViewListener (event)
    print(event.phase)
end

local function onRowRender(event) 
    local row = event.row
    local rowTitle = display.newText(row, song[row.index].artist, 10,0, nil, 14)
        rowTitle:setTextColor(0,0,0)
end

local function onRowTouch(event)

end

-- tableview
local tableView = widget.newTableView {
    left = 0, top = 0, 
    onRowRender = onRowRender, onRowTouch = onRowTouch, listener = scrollListener
}

for i = 1, count do
    local rowHeight = 40
    local rowColor = {
        default = {255,255,255}
    }
    local lineColor = { 220,220,220}

    tableView:insertRow {
        rowHeight = rowHeight,
        rowColor = rowColor,
        lineColor = lineColor,
        rowid = song[count].id
    }

end
```

this is working fine.  it displays the result data from sql.  I want to implement the ontouch function by passing additional unique properties from the same sql table into each row, so that when the row is clicked, it will then get that data specifically to that clicked row.  I have tried adding custom variables to rowTitle (rowTitle.someData = 'test') but this doesn't seem to pass onto onRowTouch event.

Answer (score 2):

I actually fixed this by adding `params` as one of the properties inside insertRow. I then call it inside

I added another array inside the sql loop :

```
song[count].id = row.id
```

I added custom parameter like so:

```
tableView:insertRow({
    -- ...
    params = {paramID = song[i].id}
})
```

I then call it inside touch function like so

```
local function onRowTouch(event)
    print (event.target.params.paramID)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try it.

```
function loadData()
local sql1 = "select unit.id, builtin_list.* from unit inner join builtin_list on unit.id = builtin_list.unit_id group by artist order by artist asc";
local projects = {}
for row in db:nrows(sql1) do
projects[#projects+1] =
{
    artist = row.artist;
}
end
return projects
end
```

local data = loadData()

Within row access Data:

```
local row = event.row
local id = row.index
data[id].artist
```